# Payza payment gateway advance button integration

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing

I am trying to integrate payza payment gateway, What I have done:
I have followed example given at their API documentation page for advance button integration. Here is code from this official [example](https://docs.payza.com/v1.0/reference#advanced-integration):

```
<form method="post" action="https://secure.payza.com/checkout">
<input type="hidden" name="ap_merchant" value="payza_merchant@test.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_purchasetype" value="item"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_itemname" value="MP3 Player"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_amount" value="50"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_currency" value="USD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_quantity" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_itemcode" value="HIJ123"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_description" value="Audio equipment"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_taxamount" value="2.49"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_additionalcharges" value="1.19"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_shippingcharges" value="7.99"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="ap_discountamount" value="4.99"/>
<input type="hidden" name="apc_1" value="Blue"/>
<input type="hidden" name="apc_2" value="UE plug"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_ipnversion" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_testmode" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ap_returnurl" value="http://www.example.com/thankyou.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="ap_cancelurl" value="http://www.example.com/cancel.html" />

<input type="image" src="https://www.payza.com/images/payza-buy-now.png"/>
```

It is working fine with `ap_testmode="1"` when I change this to `ap_testmode="0"` and add my client's live account email it always says Button configuration is not correct.

[image]

I have tried several variation deployed on staging environment to check if it is due to local dev environment but no success.

Have googled a lot but no helpful information. Anybody can point me on right direction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of search and debugging It turns out Payza merchant account register domain name with the business account verification, my client's account was registered with another domain and he was trying to add that email on new domain. Here is a link on paypza api documentation page for that error information.
https://docs.payza.com/docs/biz-manual-standard-integration-payment-buttons#section-why-isnt-my-payza-payment-button-working-properly

> The Payza Payment Button has been placed on the wrong website or on a website that has not been submitted for Website Review. Before your buttons will work, your must submit your website for review.